# Dealing with unordered XY points to create a polygon shapefile in R

Tags: r, polygon, qgis, r-sp

I've inherited a geodatabase of polygons of lakes for which I am trying to create sampling grids on each lake. My current strategy is to export spatial data to CSV, use R to run a loop to create the grids on each lake, and then write to a new shapefile. However, here is my problem, when exporting to a CSV the WKT strings get messed up and put onto different lines. Okay, no problem, I moved on to exporting just the geometry to CSV so that I get X-Y values. When I simply plot the points they look perfect (using plot(y~x)), but the points are not in order. So, when I transform the data to a `SpatialPolygon` in the `sp` package in R using the following sequence:

```
XY-points -> Polygon -> Polygons -> SpatialPolygon
```

and then plot the `SpatialPolygon` I get this:

[image]

I know this is an artifact of incorrectly ordered points, because when I order the points by X and then by Y and run the same procedure here is what I get:

[image]

This is what the correct plotting is supposed to look like (X-Y data plotted with open circles):

[image]

Here is a short reproducible example of what I am trying to deal with:

```
library(sp)
# correct polygon
data <- data.frame(x=c(1:10, 10:1), y=c(5:1, 1:10, 10:6))
# plot(y~x, data=data)
correct.data.points <- rbind(data, data[1,]) # to close the ring for a polygon
correct.data.coords <- as.matrix(cbind(correct.data.points))
correct.data.poly <- Polygon(correct.data.coords, hole=F)
correct.data.poly <- Polygons(list(correct.data.poly), ID=0)
correct.data.poly.sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(correct.data.poly))
plot(correct.data.poly.sp)


# incorrect polygon
scr.data <- data[c(sample(1:20)),]
# plot(y~x, data=scr.data)
scr.data.points <- rbind(scr.data, scr.data[1,]) # to close the ring for a polygon
scr.data.coords <- as.matrix(cbind(scr.data.points))
scr.data.poly <- Polygon(scr.data.coords, hole=F)
scr.data.poly <- Polygons(list(scr.data.poly), ID=0)
scr.data.poly.sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(scr.data.poly))
plot(scr.data.poly.sp)
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for any help or insight anyone can provide. Also, for reference I am using QGIS 2.6.0 and the MMQGIS Python plugin to do the geometry exporting.

Comment: Fix the data input problem. Post a reproducible example of data before you destroy the ordering. Otherwise you will get stuck with trying to create an envelope and those are pretty tricky. You can see what you get with searching on "convex hull".

Comment: Why smash the structure of the data to csv? Try reading the geodatabase with readOGR from rgdal: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2014-July/021339.html

Comment: @mdsummer. Thanks, but I didn't see a GDB driver in ogrDrivers(). I am using R3.1.1 and rdgal0.9-1. I did find a workaround to my original WKT problem, though. Turns out QGIS exports to Excel as default for CSV exports, and user-friendly Excel was cutting off the WKT string at x character length. So, I just copied the attribute table from QGIS into a .txt file and read data to R with read.table(file, sep='\t'). This way the WKT geometry came through in tact.